# Cast the Elasticsearch.Net client to the standard Nest client

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I see that the Elasticsearch.Net client supports failover connections.  Is there a way to cast this client to the standard Nest client?

I've already built all of my mapping, searching and indexing with Nest.  I'm looking for a way to support failover connections without having to redo everything I've done so far.

I've tried typical methods of casting.  Both snippets below are invalid casts.

```
var client = new ElasticsearchClient(config);
return (ElasticClient)client;

var client = new ElasticsearchClient(config);
return client as ElasticClient;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need to cast `ElasticClient` as it already built upon the `ElasticseachClient` and has support for failover via connection pooling. From the [Nest - Connecting Documentation](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/nest/connecting.html):

> If you want a failover client instead of passing a Uri pass an IConnectionPool see the [Elasticsearch.Net documentation on cluster failover](http://nest.azurewebsites.net/elasticsearch-net/cluster-failover.html) all of its implementations can also be used with NEST.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this helps or not but if you use the NestClient you can also get access to the lower level Elasticsearch client like so

```
    var client = new ElasticClient(settings);
    var rawClient = client.Raw;
```